# The type attribute of SCRIPT and STYLE elements in HTML?

Tags: html, content-type

I heard (from Crockford) what type attributes on LINK and SCRIPT elements are superfluous when those elements are used to load external resources. (Because the HTTP response determines the content-type of the resource.)

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="foo.css">

<script src="foo.js"></script>
```

But what about the case when non-HTML code is placed inline inside the STYLE and SCRIPT elements?

```
<style>
    /* inline CSS rules */
</style>

<script>
    // inline JavaScript code
</script>
```

Is setting the type attribute in those cases recommended?
Are there any issues when we choose to omit the type attribute?

Comment: A few more answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715953/do-we-need-type-text-css-for-link-in-html5/7716130#7716130

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For HTML 4, the answer is simple: The `type` attribute is required for both [`<script>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) and [`<style>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/styles.html#h-14.2.2).

> Authors must supply a value for this attribute; there is no default value for this attribute.

As far as I know, the default fallback in all browsers in its absence is `text/javascript` and `text/css`, respectively. It's widespread (though invalid) practice to not use the type attribute. I would still specify it to avoid browser problems.

HTML 5 accepts reality and declares these values as official defaults for [`<style>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-style-element) and  [`<script>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#script). I'm pretty sure this makes it okay to leave them off for inline content as well, which will be parsed using the correct content type automatically.