# Can I use an HTML <style> element without line-breaks?

Tags: css

```
<style>/* foo */ body{color:red}div{color:green}</style>
```

So, I have this `<style>` element. It has a comment, and then several CSS rules. It is my CSS reset code, so I would like to have it in one line, without a single line break inside the `<style>` element.

Is this OK with browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is. Whitespace is insignificant in CSS except in at-rules, as the descendant combinator, and when using it to separate property values (e.g. in shorthand properties), among other things.

The [CSS2.1 syntax documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-CSS21-20020802/syndata.html) talks about the effect of whitespace (or lack thereof) on your CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (provided you include proper attributes on your `<style>` element :).

Comment: Well, I don't :) I am not aware of any browser issue related to leaving out the type attribute on STYLE elements.

Comment: It is [syntactically invalid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3) to omit the `type` attribute. _"Authors must supply a value for this attribute; there is no default value for this attribute."_ See also [this Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668910/the-type-attribute-of-script-and-style-elements-in-html/4072325#4072325).

Comment: Notice that you are linking to my own question `:D`. I care about browser support, not so much about standards compliance. However, it seems that HTML5 doesn't care about the `type` attribute: *"The default value for the type attribute, which is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/css"."* http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#attr-style-type

Comment: @ŠimeVidas How amusing, I didn't notice that you were the OP for that question :) +1 for noting that HTML5 makes this attribute optional.