# How does the browser knows how to interpret the script tag?

Tags: html, coffeescript

According to this:

http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/scripts.html

The type of script my be added in the script tag. Some values are: "text/tcl", "text/javascript", "text/vbscript".

Recently I've seen in this page: [Cofeescript in 1,2,3](http://monocaffe.blogspot.com/2011/02/coffeescript-in-1-2-3.html) the following:

```
 <script src="coffee-script.js"></script>
 <script type="text/coffeescript">
         alert "Hello CoffeeScript!"
 </script>
```

And works great! ( I had to download the cofeescript library and use the one in the extra folder )

My question is. How does the browser knows that a given script should be handled? I have no idea.

Comment: Did you click submit before completing it?

Comment: @Oscar weird. I can edit it fine

Comment: You must have really upset Joel.  :)

Comment: @Oscar :-) Voted to delete? Can't you delete the question and start a new one?

Comment: hehe I've found the reason. The &lt;script> tag breaks SO markdown http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80431/using-htmls-script-tag-breaks-so-serverside-markdown-somehow

Comment: Some good information in the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706290/why-write-script-type-text-javascript-when-the-mime-type-is-set-by-the-server/2706617

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you can't finish your answer, it's not yet entirely clear what  your question is ;)

But the answer to this question is related: [The type attribute of SCRIPT and STYLE elements in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668910/the-type-attribute-of-script-and-style-elements-in-html)

Summary:

- `type` is indeed a required attribute in HTML 4
- it defaults to `text/javascript` in HTML 5

as far as I know, `text/javascript` is the de facto default in all modern browsers if the property is missing even in HTML 4.

Answer (score 1):

Since HTML5, the type attribute is optional (it is required in HTML4 though) and the default value is `text/javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

The browser simply recognises some specific types of script, and ignores everything else.

Internet Explorer for example recognises the type "text/javascript" and runs the script, eventhough it actually runs it as JScript.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the default in browsers is to interpret a script tag as holding JavaScript; whilst the spec that you've listed indicates that there is no default value for the `type` attribute, that doesn't mean that browsers won't provide their own default.